# Wordpres pegar o post modificado

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Preciso de uma ajuda com um query post:

Como faco para visualizar os post que foram modificado digo atualizado exemplo:

foi cadastrado um post se ele foi modificado hoje preciso exibir e o que foi modificado buscar por um um query post uma especie de query_post  de revisao

seria possivel isso? segue um  loop query_post  exemplo:

```html
<?php
$args = array(
  
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'inherit',    


  );
?>

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php if ($the_query->have_posts()): while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();?>

<!--POST QUE FORAM MODIFICADO ATUALIZADO -->

<?php the_title();?>
      
 <?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar os posts por data de modificação, ex:

```
$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'inherit', 
'orderby'     => 'modified', 
'order'       => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => -1,

);
```

Caso vc queira pegar os posts modificados hoje, adicione o parametro `date_query`:

```
$today = getdate();

$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'inherit', 
'orderby'     => 'modified', 
'order'       => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'year'  => $today['year'],
        'month' => $today['mon'],
        'day'   => $today['mday'],
    )));
```